# Error(31,64): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have below function in oracle,

```
create or replace FUNCTION CALINTEREST
( DNumber IN VARCHAR2,
  IRate IN NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER IS
    AInterest NUMERIC(17,8):=0;
    PDue NUMERIC(11,2);
    IDue NUMERIC(17,8);
    INTRate NUMERIC(5,2);
    IntDate DATE;
    IntDATEDIFF NUMERIC(6):=0;
BEGIN
BEGIN
  SELECT
  DBRD_PRI_DUE,
  DBRD_INT_DUE,
  DBRD_INT_RATE,
  DBRD_INT_DATE INTO 
            PDue 
            ,IDue 
            ,INTRate  
            ,IntDate 
        FROM
            DBRD 
        WHERE
            DBRNO = DNumber;     

        IF(INTRate = 999)
    THEN
             INTRate := IRate;
        END IF;     
    IntDATEDIFF:=Cast((Sysdate-IntDate) AS NUMBER(11,0));
        AInterest := IDue + (PDue * INTRate * IntDATEDIFF / 365 / 100);   
   END;
  RETURN AInterest; 
END;
```

I am getting below two error,
Error(31,64): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:     . ) @ % The symbol ")" was substituted for "(" to continue. 
Error(31,70): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:     . ( * % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem     <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset The symbol "(" was substituted for ")" to continue.

Comment: `Cast((Sysdate-IntDate) AS NUMBER(11,0));` should be `Cast((Sysdate-IntDate) AS NUMBER);`

Comment: And after you make the correction Griffey has indicated above ("cast" allows you to cast to "number" - you can't tell it the length of the number) and recompile, you will find several more errors. If you want help, perhaps you can explain what you want the code to do, then we can help you.

Comment: @GriffeyDog if i do make change as per you it's giving me below errors,Error(31,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(31,28): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Comment: @mathguy I want to call this function from Stored Procedure and this function should fetch values of particular record do calculations mentioned above and return the calculated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will work for you. On my machine the only errors I get on compilation have to do with the table DBRO (because I don't have a table by that name), but that doesn't mean this does the computations you want it to do. Anyway, play with it and write back if you have more questions.

I changed NUMERIC to NUMBER (the correct name of the Oracle data type for numbers), I changed the computation for IntDATEDIFF in a way that will be immediately obvious when you look at it (Trunc changes the time portion of an Oracle DATE to 00:00:00, and taking the arithmetic "minus" between two dates returns the difference as a number of days), and I removed BEGIN and END; for the inner block- there was no need for an inner block.

```
create or replace FUNCTION CALINTEREST
( DNumber IN VARCHAR2,
  IRate IN NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER IS
    AInterest NUMBER(17,8):=0;
    PDue NUMBER(11,2);
    IDue NUMBER(17,8);
    INTRate NUMBER(5,2);
    IntDate DATE;
    IntDATEDIFF NUMBER(6):=0;
BEGIN
  SELECT
  DBRD_PRI_DUE,
  DBRD_INT_DUE,
  DBRD_INT_RATE,
  DBRD_INT_DATE INTO
            PDue
            ,IDue
            ,INTRate
            ,IntDate
        FROM
            DBRD
        WHERE
            DBRNO = DNumber;
        IF(INTRate = 999)
    THEN
             INTRate := IRate;
        END IF;
    IntDATEDIFF:=trunc(Sysdate) - trunc(IntDate);
        AInterest := IDue + (PDue * INTRate * IntDATEDIFF / 365 / 100);
  RETURN AInterest;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace FUNCTION CALINTEREST(
  DNumber IN VARCHAR2,
  IRate IN NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
    PDue NUMERIC(11,2);
    IDue NUMERIC(17,8);
    INTRate NUMERIC(5,2);
    IntDate DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT DBRD_PRI_DUE, DBRD_INT_DUE, DBRD_INT_RATE, DBRD_INT_DATE
  INTO   PDue,         IDue,         INTRate,       IntDate 
  FROM   DBRD 
  WHERE  DBRNO = DNumber;     

  IF (INTRate = 999) THEN
    INTRate := IRate;
  END IF;     
  RETURN IDue + (PDue * INTRate * TRUNC(SYSDATE - IntDate) / 365 / 100); 
END;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Or moving the logic into SQL:

```
create or replace FUNCTION CALINTEREST(
  DNumber IN VARCHAR2,
  IRate IN NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  p_interest NUMBER(17,8);
BEGIN
  SELECT DBRD_INT_DUE
         + ( DBRD_PRI_DUE
             * CASE DBRD_INT_RATE
                    WHEN 999 THEN IRate
                    ELSE DBRD_INT_RATE
                    END
             * TRUNC( SYSDATE - DBRD_INT_DATE )
             / 365
             / 100
           )
  INTO   p_interest 
  FROM   DBRD 
  WHERE  DBRNO = DNumber;     

  RETURN p_interest; 
END;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Comment: trunc(sysdate-IntDate) is probably the wrong formula, it should be trunc(sysdate) - trunc(intdate); I believe this is how banks compute interest "days." The first formula will give an answer that's one day short if the current time in sysdate is less than the time portion of intdate.  Also, NUMERIC is not an Oracle SQL or PL/SQL data type.

Comment: @mathguy That is not the logic that the OP used in his own code - there it is `Sysdate-IntDate` and then the result is cast to an integer (i.e. truncated). I  consider that the OP know the business logic that is required and go with what he requests not what I think it ought to be.

Comment: I don't doubt the OP knows the business logic; rather, I doubt that he knew how to express it correctly in code. The OP will be the judge of that, of course.